# sqlite python cursor function error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import os 

db_folder = "D:/Python/databases/accounts.sqlite"
db = sql.connect(db_folder)
im = sql.Cursor()

im.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'accounts' (              
          id    TEXT  DEFAULT 'account' UNIQUE             
          pw    TEXT  DEFAULT 'password
          email TEXT UNIQUE 
)
""")

datas = [
  ("eren.arc1","1236"),
  ("ern.arc"),
  (none,none,"erenarici@gmail.com")
]

if not os.path.exists(db_folder):
    for data in datas : 
        im.execute("""INSERT INTO 'accounts' VALUES (?,?,?)""",datas)
    db.commit()
```

I ran this code and I got this error:

```
File "databases/db4.py", line 6, in <module>
im = sql.Cursor()
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

What is the problem? I did not see argument frequently in cursor function. 
Note: I used `cursor()` but then I took sqlite3 hasn't got cursor attribute error. Then I changed it to `Cursor()`.

Comment: You have to pass you db connection into the cursor. The cursor does not know where to connect. Try `sql.Cursor(db)'  I may be wrong I have not tested this

Comment: `cursor()` without capital C ?

Comment: I dont know. Test it

Comment: I looked at the docs it is lower case

Comment: @Joe I dont know exactly why but it runned Thanks

Comment: According to the docs it should look like this:  `im = db.cursor()`  If you have trouble make it look like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import os 

sqlite_file = "db.sqlite"
conn = sql.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (
          id TEXT DEFAULT 'account' UNIQUE,
          pw TEXT DEFAULT 'password',
          email TEXT UNIQUE);""")

items = [
  ("id1", "pw1", "user1@gmail.com"),
  ("id2", "pw2", "user2@gmail.com"),
  ("id3", "pw3", "user3@gmail.com")
]

for item in items: 
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (?,?,?);""", item)

c.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts(id, email) VALUES ('id4', 'user4@gmail.com');""")
c.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts(email) VALUES ('account@gmail.com');""")

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts'):
    print(row)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Output:

```
('id1', 'pw1', 'user1@gmail.com')
('id2', 'pw2', 'user2@gmail.com')
('id3', 'pw3', 'user3@gmail.com')
('id4', 'password', 'user4@gmail.com')
('account', 'password', 'account@gmail.com')
```

If you respect the order of each field, you can check the length of the `item` tuple to do insertions in the loop:

```
for item in items: 
    if len(item) == 3:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (?,?,?);""", item)
    elif len(item) == 2:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts(pw, email) VALUES (?,?);""", item)
    elif len(item) == 1:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts(email) VALUES (?);""", item)
```

But `(none, none, 'email')` doesn't make sense here, to insert NULL data use the keyword `NULL` (if python it is `None` not `none` also).